# My interesting tags are falling off

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-watching

I have quite a lot of **interesting** tags, and from time to time over the last week or so I notice that one or more have disappeared from the list. Then I add them back in. I think this started happening at the same time as the extra pop up menu over interesting tags to uninteresting them. I think I am accidentally clicking that. Is there a way to suppress it? I was ok with the red X next to the tag and the extra menu is distracting at best for me, and might be causing this "oops I dropped a tag" situation as well.

This is how they look:
[alt text http://www.gregcons.com/sopopup.jpg](http://www.gregcons.com/sopopup.jpg)
[alt text http://www.gregcons.com/sopopup2.jpg](http://www.gregcons.com/sopopup2.jpg)

I don't think I have greasemonkey. Not on purpose anyway.

Comment: ...extra popup menu? I still see red Xs. Is this some script you installed that replaced it?

Comment: Greasemonkey strikes again.

Comment: Is this a shared computer?

Comment: @guys: new feature -- click one of your interesting tags, then hover over any tag that appears in the results.

Comment: This feature was *just* rolled out. It hadn't even shown up on my machine until just about now. It is also only visible on the Questions pages.

Comment: Yes, I've almost clicked on "remove" by accident a few times.  Very poor placement of that drop-down.  This strikes me as ironic given this post: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/the-opposite-of-fitts-law.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was never the intent for this menu to appear on the actual Interested or Ignored list itself. That is now fixed.

However, on any `/tagged/` page you can mouse over a visible tag to get that menu.

Comment: This works for me. I am pretty sure the accidental clicks are when I'm using the Interesting list on the right, not the tags under each question. I use those much less often and typically only click them if they're not already an interesting tag, so the chance of losing a tag goes down dramatically.

Answer (score 2):

+1.  I'm not sure if I even like this feature.  It seems rather pointless and redundant, I can't understand why anyone would have requested it (if it was even requested).  It's already very easy to add/remove interesting/ignored tags.

At the very least, you'll get used to it sooner or later and stop accidentally removing your interested tags.