# Interesting/ignored wildcards are lumped with the base tagname in the new popup menu

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-watching, ignored-tags, wildcards

If you have a wildcard tag as one of your interesting or ignored tags, then the [new popup menu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54507/my-interesting-tags-are-falling-off) that lets you remove or add tags inline will incorrectly link it with the base tag name (truncating the wildcard operator).

For example, if I set my Interesting tags to include [[status*]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status~), then if I look at the tag [[status]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status), it tells me I can remove the tag "status" from my interesting tags. Doing so would remove [status*] from my interesting tags. If I had both [status] and [status*] as interesting tags, it would remove both, but in most cases you'll only have the single wildcard. But adding, naturally, will not add the wildcard back, you'll have to manually add it back.

Only the base tag will show this. So, expanding the earlier example, the [status-completed] tag will not give me the option to remove my wildcard.

Comment: This is pre-emptitive action, but I'm actually under the impression that this bug is the same one [reported here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59793/cant-add-interesting-tag-that-is-a-substring-of-existing-interesting-tag), where it's any substring of a preference, not just wildcards. Since that one covers it better, I'm voting to close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my pre-emptitive impression was correct. [Geoff's fix also corrected this problem, as the underlying problem was exactly the same one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59793/cant-add-interesting-tag-that-is-a-substring-of-existing-interesting-tag/60274#60274).