# Simpler interested-tag marking

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

Why isn't there a "Mark as Interesting" link on each tag's page, so we don't have to type each tag in by hand to add to our interested list?

I can't think of any reason why marking tags as interesting shouldn't be just as easy as unmarking them, especially on a [tag's page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23).

Answer (score 2):

There is a context menu for just this which pops up when you hover over a tag on its page. Actually, the menu will also pop up for all tags listed under questions on that page as well, in case you found any others you were interested in.

For example, on your c# tag page link, if I hover over the c# tag it produces a dropdown that lets me remove it from my interesting tags (as it already is one), or add it to my ignored tags.

[image: Image depicting the aforementioned dropdown]

Comment: I use SO every day and I never knew this. There's a bit of a delay, so maybe I just click too fast. I'll use this from now on, but I would still recommend an obvious link on the tag page with a helpful hint like "hover over tags for easy marking".

Comment: @FreshCode It wasn't very loudly publicized and it's only on tag pages that it occurs, so it's not too surprising you didn't know about it. For the curious, the feature has actually been around since [June 21st](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54507/my-interesting-tags-are-falling-off).

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know why this is *only* on the tag page, and not active everywhere?